# How do I download and install wireless drivers with NO internet?

Tags: wireless, drivers, hp

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 alongside Windows 7 on a HP dv6700 laptop. I can access wireless internet from my Windows side, but not on Ubuntu. I have NO wired connection available to me to use.

I believe the wireless does not work on Ubuntu because I need the appropriate drivers. However, I can't download them while in Ubuntu because of the lack of any internet connection.

My questions, then, are i) how do I download the driver to a flash drive (and where do I get the appropriate one) using the Windows side, and ii) how to I then install it on my Ubuntu side?

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help! I finally it working and am online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download any package from [Ubuntu packages Web Repository](http://packages.ubuntu.com/). When you find the right package for your system, you can download the sources and compile them (it can be difficult, I recommend a specific guide) **or** you can also download the .deb package and install it with `sudo dpkg -i package_name`.
So:

1. Download the .deb package.
2. Move it to your Linux system.
3. Install it with dpkg or another package manager.

Remember to select the **proper** architecture (multi-core PC are always 64 bit).
Have a nice day.

Edit: if a package has dependencies dowload and install them **before** the package with the drivers.

Answer (score 0):

1) Try Keryx Project - https://launchpad.net/keryxproject
2) Try Sushi Huh? - http://sushi-huh.sourceforge.net/
3) Try APTonCD - http://aptoncd.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Camicri Cube** - https://launchpad.net/camicricube 
Still under development but functional enough to be an offline package management system. 
Tested in Ubuntu 12.04, Linux Mint Maya and Microsoft Windows XP, 7.. **32 bit only**